# C# Painting a form into a MetaFile graphics object

Tags: c#, winforms, vector-graphics, zedgraph

I hope that question was not asked before. I could not find anything specific in this regard. I have a complicated custom drawn form that I would lake to save as a vector graphic (emf) using the MetaFile class in C#.
Somehow I just can't get it to work. I always end up with a 1KB empty file and maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

This is my code so far. Am I missing something?

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height));
IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();

Metafile imageMetafile = new Metafile(filepath, hdc);

using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(imageMetafile)) 
{
       imageGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
       imageGraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
       this.InvokePaint(this, new PaintEventArgs(imageGraphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height)));
}

g.ReleaseHdc();
g.Dispose();
```

I got parts of this code structure from the source code of ZedGraph. However ZedGraph then feeds everything through its own Draw() methods that stanard winforms don't have. This is where I thought I might be able to use InvokePaint to accomplish the same result but without any success.

As a side note: The control element I try to paint is already on screen at this moment and I am calling this code from the UI thread.

How would one get a Control element use a custom graphics object instead of the regular "paint on screen" graphics object?

EDIT: Just to further clarify. I don't have an issue with generating vector graphics in general. The MetaFile graphics route works fine if I just start drawing shapes or even bitmaps into it. The only issue I face is that I can't get my UI control to use THAT graphics object instead of the default "print-to-screen" graphics object.

Comment: And why you think it's even possible? I mean, I'm not win forms specialist, but why you think form paints itself using vector graphics (so with things like `DrawRectangle`, `DrawLine` etc) and not bitmap graphics (fill this range of pixels with this color)?

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing builtin in .NET to save a MetaFile as an ".EMF" file. Can you try with a code similar to this one: https://pastebin.com/dwPcpsXD

Comment: well, saving the MetaFile as EMF is not the problem. That part works fine in other instances when I use the graphics object provided by the MetaFile and just draw into it. I just can't get my general UI control to draw into THAT graphics object instead of the screen graphics object.

Comment: @Evk: At least for that particular control I know that it uses DrawRectangle etc. because I overwrote parts of that drawing routine. Could well be that the winform draws it as bitmaps. However I can not even get that to be drawn into my EMF file so I guess the problem is somewhere else (it could simply be that there is no way to provide a control with a custom graphics object).

Comment: Have you even looked to the code I gave you? PS: you must use the @ prefix to address comments to a user. I just happen to pass by again.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Sorry, that one slipped my attention. I will check and come back

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageMetafile = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);

using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(imageMetafile))
{
    imageGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    imageGraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    imageGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, this.Size);
    imageMetafile.Save(filepath);
}
```

Comment: While I mentioned that the UI element is currently on screen, it is unfortunately not fully visible on screen (rather being within a Scrollable panel).
Is there also a solution that would work with that situation?

Comment: However, the bigger issue with that method is that I now have a regular pixel image within a vector graphic format instead of a real vector graphic image.